# In SQLalchemy, can I have a column with multiple strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

For the following code, I have the mapping and an example of a "cookie" that contains some info I want to add to the SQLalchemy through python. As you can see some fields like Farmloc, TreasureMap, and Crafts all have multiple entries they point to. I searched and couldn't find much other than Enum, but that was giving me some trouble. Is there a better means than what I've done here. Using Python3.6.1 and SQLalchemy 1.1.11

```
import csv, sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey, Numeric, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import sqlite3
from enum import Enum, auto
import enum
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True) #TEST DB
    
Base = declarative_base()

class Crystal(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'crystals'
    dbID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ItemName = Column(String, index=True, nullable=False) #Full name, (ie. Earth Shard, Wind Crystal, Fire Cluster)
    ItemType = Column(String) #Fire, Earth, Wind, Ice, Water ONLY
    ItemPow = Column(String) #Shard, Crystal, Cluster ONLY
    Farmloc = Column(String) #Where player can farm
    Retainer = Column(Boolean) #If retainer can farm
    RetainerQ = Column(Integer) #Quantity retainer gets
    Levee = Column(Boolean) #Any Levees rewards these.
    TreasureMap = Column(String) #False=NO, otherwise Types listed
    Desynthed = Column(String) #False=NO, otherwise Herb1, Herb2, Ore1, etc
    Crafts = Column(String) #Crafts associated with (ie Earth w LWR)
    Price = Column(Integer) #MB price (Should be used as ref for all craftables)

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
    
cc_cookie = Crystal(dbID = 1,
                        ItemName= 'Wind Cluster',
                        ItemType = 'Wind',
                        ItemPow = 'Cluster',
                        Farmloc = 'The Dravanian Hinterlands, Mor Dhona',
                        Retainer = False,
                        RetainerQ = 0,
                        Levee = False,
                        TreasureMap = 'Dragonskin Treasure Map,Gaganaskin Treasure Map,Gazelleskin Treasure Map,Leather Buried Treasure Map',
                        Desynthed = 'Clary Sage,Furymint,Highland Oregano,Windtea Leaves',
                        Crafts = 'CRP,GSM,LWR,WVR',
                        Price = 500)       


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session.add(cc_cookie)
session.commit()
```

Comment: Are you planning on staying with sqlite, or will you be using some other DB in the long run?

Comment: I'm very new to database. For now I'm sticking to it, unless you have something else in mind.

Comment: You can sort of have array columns in sqlite, though it has no native support. You could [store JSON in a text column](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#marshal-json-strings). [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org) has real array types, if you make that jump some day.

Comment: Alright. I'll consider my options then. Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Check out the built-in [class sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY)

For example:

```
TreasureMap = Column(ARRAY(String))
```

Side note: as per convention all column names are all lowercase and under score separated (e.g. `treasure_map` over `TreasureMap`.)

Comment: Thank you. I came across that bit in the documentation, but this is the line that made me not even jump into it.

"This type serves as the basis for all ARRAY operations. However, currently only the PostgreSQL backend has support for SQL arrays in SQLAlchemy"

Is PostgreSQL just an import or it's an SQL system like SQLalchemy?

Comment: PostgreSQL is a database, SQLAlchemy an SQL client library/ORM.